# What's the word for enticing someone and eloping with them?

Tags: single-word-requests

What word(verb) should go in the blank in the sentence below?

*He----X's wife/girlfriend and married her.*

Basically I need a word that means **enticed, and later eloped with** (X's wife/girlfriend.)

I cannot think of a proper word for this context, and so I would appreciate any help forthcoming.

Comment: If a bit of word play is acceptable, purloined perhaps? You might also suggest the enticement idea by saying she married him.

Comment: Sounds good, but i think it's just a fancy way of saying _stole her wife_ (though it does have undertones of trust breach.) I'm looking for a verb that neatly captures _enticing, followed by elopement._

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not sure you will easily find one single word that contains both connotations (of enticing and eloping). I would express your sentence in this way

> He ***[seduced](https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/another-word-for/seduce.html)*** X's wife/girlfriend ***into eloping with*** him.

[Longman](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/seduce) defines the expression ***seduce somebody into doing something*** as

> to make someone want to do something by making it seem very attractive or interesting to them:
>
> - Leaders are people who can seduce other people into sharing their
>   dream.

***Entice into doing something*** is just as good.

Certainly, eloping doesn't always end up in marriage, so you may consider saying:

> He ***seduced*** X's wife/girlfriend ***into marrying*** him.

which would hint at the fact that the marriage was possible through an elopement.

Comment: And, of course, it also means to entice someone to have illicit sexual relations with you.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe *to court them*? It's the closest word I could come up with.

From [Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/amp/english/court):

> To court a particular person, group, or country means to try to please them or improve your relations with them, often so that they will do something that you want them to do.

And from [LDOCE](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/court):

> to try hard to please someone, especially because you want something from them.

Comment: I don't think it connotes elopement, though.

Answer (score 0):

In the common law this was called "alienation of affections" (only applying to a spouse (i.e., not a girlfriend)): https://www.law.cornell.edu/wex/alienation_of_affections#.

The closest one-word equivalent verb is probably "seduced" although as the linked source notes there are other types of alienation of affection (e.g., encouraging someone to divorce).

Another word that comes to mind is "beguiled": "to engage the interest of by or as if by guile":
https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/beguile.
Admittedly neither "seduce" or "beguile" necessarily includes the idea of elopement.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).